# Cannot open VirtualBox VM installed on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, reinstall

I tried to reinstall the VirtualBox after upgrading the system from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS which went well. Now after reinstalling the VirtualBox I got this error.
I have deleted the /home/user/win7 Activated with Antivirus/win7.vbox' file by mistake and its permanent delete from trash as well now how do i recover it ? :(

[image]

Comment: Did you delete just that file or the entire folder? Search your compute for .vdi or .vmdk files (virtual hard drives).

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the vm file (vdi,vhd, qcow, etc) create new machine, select 'use existing drive' and point to your vm file.

Comment: No FIle found :( there is no file in vbox folder to use existing option

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens if the host OS crashes or you pull the plug on it, leaving the .vbox file unsaved.

You can try steps provided in question:

[Oracle virtual box inaccessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217193/oracle-virtual-box-inaccessible)

Comment: Its not working..... my main os is ubuntu and the other processor was wind 7 professional